# How long takes populating catalog in SQL Server 2008 R2 when update a row?

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 with FullText search feature installed.

I created a catalog and fulltext index on a table (let's say `Table1`). I used the following commands (sql queries):

```
USE MyDatabase
EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [MY_CATALOG_] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Table1 (Column1)
    KEY INDEX PK_KEY_TABLE1_
    ON MY_CATALOG_ WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

`WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;` means auto-populate, right ?

When I use a stored procedure to update a row from `Table1` and I use search query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE CONTAINS(Column1,'modifiedName')
```

but no results were found.

I've checked the populate status is 0 (idle). I have to go in Sql Management studio and choose rebuild catalog. And then works (mean I found results what I expected)

**My question:** how long takes populating catalog in sql server ? My table (Table1) has 2000 rows.

Comment: Is your modified row returned if you run a full population?

Comment: If I run manually the full population, the the results of search is fine, give the correct results. Otherwise not. That's my question: how long or how sql server proceed with population when a row is modified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ther is no answer. IIRC the change gets logged and full text index processes them async one by one - so the time is "random" - i.e. depending on the amount of changes, the size of the queue.

If you ahve things properly configured it should show up "after some time", but that should - unless you do a TON of updates in one moment - be relatively fast.

This is in line with the business approach (text repositories) where a time delay can be accepted.